# Is there a way to make a specific item in a multiselect disabled?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm really just wondering if anyone has stumbled across this...

In the Widgets API documentation for the Multiselect widget in Google App Maker, the "Styles" section includes a style name for a disabled item:

`.app-MultiSelect-Item.disabled`   Style for the disabled item or items.

I have a case where I'm adding options and values to a multiselect by script based on data pulled from elsewhere. The initial values include the currently selected set of choices, but based on other actions taken by the user, they may not be eligible (via our internal rules and processes) to make that choice anymore.

If there's a way to set a specific item as disabled, I'm envisioning being able to style it with a strike through to communicate that even though that choice is selected now, it's not available as a new choice, and it's going to be removed from the other data source.

So it might be like this:

X Choice A
_  Choice B
X <del>Choice C</del>
_ <del>Choice D</del>

Thoughts?